Как в одном сообщении от телеграм бота отправить текст и фото, а также работающие Inline кнопки?
Я недавно начал писать своего телеграм бота. Не очень понимаю какие-то базовые вещи и термины.
Проблема заключается в том что я не могу сделать так, чтобы Inline кнопки работали когда бот отправляет текст и фотографию. (При отправке ТОЛЬКО текста - всё нормально).
Версия с отправкой только текста и работающими Inline кнопками
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    l1_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('1', callback_data='level1_1')
    l1_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('2', callback_data='level1_2')
    markup.row(l1_1, l1_2)
    l1_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('3', callback_data='level1_3')
    l1_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('4', callback_data='level1_4')
    markup.row(l1_3, l1_4)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Текст \nТекст</b>', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup )

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data)
def check_callback_data(callback):
    if callback.data == 'level1_1':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=5)
            l2_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', callback_data='level2_1')
            l2_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', callback_data='level2_2')
            markup.row(l2_1, l2_2)
            l2_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', callback_data='level2_3')
            l2_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', callback_data='level2_4')
            markup.row(l2_3, l2_4)
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.id,
                                  text='Текст', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup)

и т.д
Версия с отправкой и текста, и фотографией, но без работающих Inline кнопок. (Ошибка вылетает на моменте нажатия на неё)
def start(photo):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    l1_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('1', callback_data='level1_1')
    l1_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('2', callback_data='level1_2')
    markup.row(l1_1, l1_2)
    l1_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('3', callback_data='level1_3')
    l1_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('4', callback_data='level1_4')
    markup.row(l1_3, l1_4)
    bot.send_photo(photo.chat.id, photo=open('image.jpg',  'rb'), caption='<b>Текст \nТекст</b>', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup )

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data)
def check_callback_data(callback):
    if callback.data == 'level1_1':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=5)
            l2_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', callback_data='level2_1')
            l2_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', callback_data='level2_2')
            markup.row(l2_1, l2_2)
            l2_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', callback_data='level2_3')
            l2_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', callback_data='level2_4')
            markup.row(l2_3, l2_4)
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.id,
                                  text='Текст', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup)

При нажатии на Inline кнопки вылетает ошибка:
A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: there is no text in the message to edit
Был бы рад любой помощи!

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что нельзя изменять текст сообщения или добавлять кнопки к сообщению с фотографией. Это объясняет, почему вы получаете ошибку "Bad Request: there is no text in the message to edit".
Но можно обойти эту проблему, отправив фотографию и кнопки отдельными сообщениями. Можно использовать метод bot.send_photo() для отправки фотографии с подписью и затем отправить кнопки в отдельном сообщении, используя метод bot.send_message().
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    photo = open('image.jpg', 'rb') # Открываем фотографию для отправки
    caption = '<b>Текст \nТекст</b>'
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    l1_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('1', callback_data='level1_1')
    l1_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('2', callback_data='level1_2')
    markup.row(l1_1, l1_2)
    l1_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('3', callback_data='level1_3')
    l1_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('4', callback_data='level1_4')
    markup.row(l1_3, l1_4)

    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption=caption, parse_mode='HTML') # Отправляем фотографию с подписью
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите вариант:', reply_markup=markup) # Отправляем сообщение с кнопками

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data)
def check_callback_data(callback):
    if callback.data == 'level1_1':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=5)
        l2_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', callback_data='level2_1')
        l2_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', callback_data='level2_2')
        markup.row(l2_1, l2_2)
        l2_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', callback_data='level2_3')
        l2_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', callback_data='level2_4')
        markup.row(l2_3, l2_4)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Выбрано: 1', reply_markup=markup) # Отправляем сообщение с обновленными кнопками


Правильно, когда вы отправляете медиа там нет текста - там подпись (caption).
Что бы изменить подпись, нужно использовать метод editMessageCaption:

Use this method to edit captions of messages. On success, if the
edited message is not an inline message, the edited Message is
returned, otherwise True is returned.

Из документации Телебот:
async edit_message_caption(caption: str, chat_id: int | str | None = None, message_id: int | None = None, inline_message_id: str | None = None, parse_mode: str | None = None, caption_entities: List[MessageEntity] | None = None, reply_markup: InlineKeyboardMarkup | None = None) → Message | bool

У вас должно быть примерно следующее:
bot.edit_message_caption(caption = 'Новая подпись', chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.id, parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup)


Простите, не очень понимаю, как это применить. Можно чуть поподробнее?

@zywowo видимо ошибся, когда копировал из вашего кода. Что бы изменить подпись используйте bot.edit_message_caption, а не bot.edit_message_text
